# Xcode / Xamarin OSX App : UISlider with custom steps

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

Im building a Xamrain native OSX app. I need to build a UI Slider, Text input and number stepper to represent shutter speeds.  But as the shutter speeds are not evenly sequential, I cant see a way to do it.

I already have this ui element for decibels and percents, where the three components all bind to a model for their values, which works great...

[image]

This basically has a numerical range 0-800 for example, and a number formatter for the text input.

But the shutter speeds are 1/25, 1/30, 1/60, 1/90, 1/100 etc etc.

Not an even distribution, and not a numerical range.  I could convert them into milliseconds (so 1/25 would be 40), but the steps are still not even.

Any ideas on how this would be possible in a native OSX Xamarin app?

Can you make a stepper with uneven steps?
Or is there way to map it to a indexed array perhaps, and on change get an object from the array by index to get the actual values?

Im worried that with the number formatting and the data binding it will get far to complicated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did in a prototype using a `UISlider` (I converted it do a custom control later):

Assuming you have these two arrays:

```
float[] shutterSpeeds = new float[] { 1 / 1000f, 1 / 500f, 1 / 250f, 1 / 60f, 1 / 30f, 1 / 15f, 1 / 8f, 1 / 4f, 1 / 2f, 1f };
string[] shutterSpeedsLabel = new string[] { "1/1000", "1/500", "1/250", "1/60", "1/30", "1/15", "1/8", "1/4", "1/2", "1" };
```

#### `UISlider` setup:

```
uiSlider.Value = shutterSpeeds[0];
uiSlider.MinValue = shutterSpeeds[0];
uiSlider.MaxValue = shutterSpeeds[shutterSpeeds.Length - 1];
uiSlider.Continuous = true;
uiSlider.ValueChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    uiLabel.Text = shutterSpeedsLabel[SnapTofStop(sender as UISlider).Index];
};
uiSlider.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => 
{
    var slider = sender as UISlider;
    slider.Value = SnapTofStop(sender as UISlider).fStop;
};
```

#### `SnapTofStop` method:

```
(float fStop, int Index) SnapTofStop(UISlider slider)
{
    var snapToValue = shutterSpeeds.Reverse().TakeWhile(_ => _.CompareTo(slider.Value) >= 0).Last();
    var snapToIndex = Array.FindIndex(shutterSpeeds, _ => _.CompareTo(snapToValue) == 0);
    return (snapToValue, snapToIndex);
}
```

Note: This produces a non-linear effect on the UISlider since the shutter speeds are close to an logarithmic scale. You could divide the number of fStop entries in the array to provide a "snap to" range by applying a logarithmic curve fit routine to the UISlider value to determine the closest fStop thus the UISlider would provide linear "steps" to the next fStop.

You can do the same thing with the `UIStepper` and snap to an fStop value on a positive/negitive step.